# Phpstorm, xdebug and vagrant still waiting for incoming connection

Tags: php, networking, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

This is annoying me, mainly because it was working fine then all of a sudden breakpoints stopped breaking and when i checked debugger it was just waiting for incoming connection.

My vagrant machine is running on `private_ip: 192.168.13.37`

My `xdebug.ini` config is as follows:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
xdebug.remote_port = 9020
```

These are my PHPstorm debug settings:
[image]

I have a vagrant server setup in PHPstorm which has a host of `dev.website.com` which points at the correct IP in windows host file, the port is 80 and the folders are mapped correctly.

I also have PHP application set up to use the explained server which a start url of `/` .

I have clicked start listening for PHP debug connections, then clicked the little green bug icon to start debugging. This launches the project with the following query string **?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=18359** but when I look in PHPstorm in the debug window it will say `waiting for incoming connection with ide key 18359`

Any ideas how to get it working again?

**Edit**
Added xdebug log : [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/hpexUGui)

Comment: That's fantastic. **1)** And what xdebug logs do say about this situation (please provide fragment)? To what IP:port it tries to connect? **2)** If it uses correct details -- please check that it is PS who listens on xdebug port (on your PC, after you activate "phone handle" icon -- run `netstat` or any other tool that can give you such info -- make sure it's PhpStorm and not some another software) **3)** Are you sure it's not your firewall/security soft? Please confirm that you can connect from remote machine to local on that port (activate "phone handle" icon and use `telnet` from remote)

Comment: I've now just noticed the following in event log: `09:38:58 Error running Unnamed: Handler with the same session id is already registered`

Comment: This is from `idea.log` as I understand. If so -- try restarting IDE (and php processes) -- sounds like debug session is somehow hanged up (no other ideas on what it may be).

Comment: I've restarted the ide and hostpc several times, destroyed and rebuilt vagrant VM. I've added xdebug logs if they make any sense to yourself?

Comment: You have truncated the log. In any case: log clearly says that there is **communication happening** between xdebug and another side (PhpStorm?) as breakpoints are being set. Maybe they are set in wrong files? I would suggest to enable "Force break..." settings to check that. I would also delete any entries at "Settings | PHP | Servers" and configure them from scratch as per zero-config approach. No other real ideas based on your info.

Comment: Hey, did you found a solution to your problem ? I'm having the same issue, the only difference being that I have two hosts on my remote machine, one of them is working perfectly fine and the other is still waiting for any connection. My server side and my phpstorm configuration looks fine as one of the hosts is working perfectly ! I have been looking for a solution for hours, if you have one, could you add it ? Thanks !

Comment: Can you tell me what the output of running Run -> Web Server Debug Validation is please.

Answer (score 5):

Had identical problem, what helped me is setting :

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

my other settings are:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9010
xdebug.idekey=phpstorm
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2
```

Comment: xdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2 - this solved my problem! Thnx

Answer (score 2):

You say you have a server setup pointing to port 80? That could be the problem.

> I have a vagrant server setup in PHPstorm which has a host of dev.website.com which points at the correct IP in windows host file, the port is 80 and the folders are mapped correctly.

Do you use PHP Remote Debug?
[image]

If it's the server setup from the screenshot, change the port there to 9020 or whatever you desire to use.

---

**My First steps of checking why xDebug isn't working:**

Set **Break at first Line** in the PHPStorm preferences

**preferences->languages&frameworks->PHP->debug** ( search break at first )

Enable the **break at first Line** feature

Still not working?

What does your phpinfo say?
Is xDebug enabled and do all the settings match?

```
phpinfo()
```

If not try this https://xdebug.org/wizard.php and check out this [Tutorial](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm)

If so try

Is there maybe a firewall blocking your port?

No?
ok ->

```
vagrant ssh 
netstat -an | grep 9000
```

Check if the port is listening and is not blocked by anything.

I would recommend using port 9000, had issues with others.

I recently had an issue with **hhvm** blocking the port. 
I purged it from the system.

If everything looks fine, try to use phpstorms remote debug feature and map explicitly your **index.php** file of your project/s.

---

Also maybe try not to use numeric values as your idekey

**XDEBUG_SESSION_START=18359**

Most people use something like this:

**XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM**

you can add an idekey to your xdebug.so 
would look like this

```
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

Small list with xdebug parameters: https://xdebug.org/docs/basic

My current projects phpstorm config looks like this:
[image]

---

This is a plugin for setting the session cookie in the browser
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem very similar with my two hosts on remote server.

One was called dev.host.com, the other 123.host.com (which was corresponding to a temporary version number).

My problem was that dev.host.com was working perfectly fine with xdebug in phpstorm while the other host was always waiting for incoming connection.

I spent some hours to look why, but found nothing concluant by changing my xdebug parameters, my phpstorm conf, my folders permissions,... until I renamed my 123.host.com with some alphabetical characters like 'abc.host.com' and..... it started working !

So I would advise you to be careful with the name you choose for your host, I think it was not mapped correctly... Weird but solved on my side.