# PhpStorm Mappings for XDebug with Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I try to debug a project using PhpStorm+Vagrant+XDebag. And I see message in Event Log:

> **Debug session was finished without being paused.**
>   It may be caused by the mapping of the misconfiguration or not synchronized local and remote projects.

But if I enable the "Break at first line in PHP scripts" option, I see that debugging reaches a certain part of the code (screen below) and then stops:
[image]

> **Waiting for incoming  connection whit ide key '17265'.

I read several articles, but did not find the right solution for me.

- [Phpstorm, xdebug and vagrant still waiting for incoming connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096056/phpstorm-xdebug-and-vagrant-still-waiting-for-incoming-connection?rq=1)
- [PhpStorm mapping paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35836875/phpstorm-mapping-paths)
- [Override Server Path Mappings Dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/override-server-path-mappings-dialog.html)

The mappings of my project:

- **Local path** - /home/pol/Projects/serialsnote (my project in PhpStorm)
- **Deployment path** - /home/pol/Boxes/lamp/project (vagrant folder)
- **Web path** - 192.168.10.10/ (Absolute path on server /var/www/html)

Settings of project:

Deployment:
[image]
[image]

PHP (Project Configuration):
[image]

Settings Server:
[image]

P.S. Screens Debug validation
[image]

Comment: Check Xdebug log. it will tell what files are involved (remote path used).

Comment: LazyOne, I read the log but I don't understand where files are involved?  xdebug.log -  https://pastebin.com/21BtmEyf

Comment: You must be doing something wrong (the way you took the log) or you have edited it. The file that gets executed must be listed in 1st response .. but you have `stdin` there: `fileuri="dbgp://stdin"`. it should be something like `fileuri="file:///var/www/html/file.name"`